# solving P(B|A) given P(B|A'), P(B'|A), P(A)?

Tags: probability

Am I wrong in claiming $P(B|A) = 1 - P(B'|A)$ which is known?

This was part of a machine learning problem set and I'm always skeptical when I come to a solution without using all the information provided!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One may observe that
$$
\begin{align}
P(B|A)+P(\bar{B}|A)&=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}+\frac{P(A\cap \bar{B})}{P(A)}
\\\\&=\frac{P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap \bar{B})}{P(A)}
\\\\&=\frac{P(A\cap (B \cup \bar{B}))}{P(A)}
\\\\&=\frac{P(A\cap \Omega)}{P(A)}
\\\\&=\frac{P(A)}{P(A)}
\\\\&=1
\end{align}
$$ giving

> $$
> P(B|A)=1-P(\bar{B}|A)
> $$